# Azure datafactory v2 Execute Pipeline with For Each

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use "Execute Pipeline" to invoke a Pipe which has a ForEach activity. I get an error.

1. Json for Execute pipe:

```
[
    {
        "name": "pipeline3",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Test_invoke1",
                    "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "pipeline": {
                            "referenceName": "MAIN_SA_copy1",
                            "type": "PipelineReference"
                        },
                        "waitOnCompletion": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "annotations": []
        }
    }
]
```

2. Jason for Invoke pipe for each activity :

```
[
    {
        "name": "MAIN_SA_copy1",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Collect_SA_Data",
                    "type": "ForEach",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "items": {
                            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.TableNames",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "batchCount": 15,
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Sink_SAdata_toDL",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Destination",
                                        "value": "@{pipeline().parameters.DLFilePath}/@{item()}"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "SqlServerSource",
                                        "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                            "value": "@concat('SELECT * FROM ',item())",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSSink"
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "parallelCopies": 1,
                                    "dataIntegrationUnits": 4
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "SrcDS_StructuringAnalytics",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ADLS",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "FilePath": "@pipeline().parameters.DLFilePath",
                                            "FileName": {
                                                "value": "@concat(item(),'.orc')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "parameters": {
                "DLFilePath": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "defaultValue": "extracts/StructuringAnalytics"
                },
                "TableNames": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "defaultValue": [
                        "fom.FOMLineItem_manual"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "variables": {
                "QryTableColumn": {
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "QryTable": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            },
            "folder": {
                "name": "StructuringAnalytics"
            },
            "annotations": []
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
    }
]
```

I get an error:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Operation on target Collect_SA_Data failed: The execution of template action 'Collect_SA_Data' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@pipeline().parameters.TableNames' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Test_invoke1",
        "details": ""
    }
]
```

Input:

```
"pipeline": {
    "referenceName": "MAIN_SA_copy1",
    "type": "PipelineReference"
},
"waitOnCompletion": true,
"parameters": {
    "DLFilePath": "extracts/StructuringAnalytics",
    "TableNames": "[\"fom.FOMLineItem_manual\"]"
}
```

Comment: I got another error after reading the 1st activity in the foreach loop,errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side.
    'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=
    Invalid object name '\"lib_service\",\"lib_transaction_type\",\"lib_utility\",
    \"lib_utility_state\",\"account_service\",\"payment_term\"'.
    ,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,
    ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,
    Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=1,Message=Invalid object name
    '\"lib_service\",\"lib_transaction_type\",\"lib_utility\"

Comment: ,\"lib_utility_state\",
    \"account_service\",\"payment_term\"'.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Sink_Atlantic_toDL",
    "details": []
}

Comment: escape character '\' is automatically getting added , how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were using the UI to set the pipeline and its parameters and I guess you expected to put the array parameter of the called pipeline as everywhere else like this:
(It is all my guess, because I just did exactly the same, with the same result)

[image: Wrong]

The trick is to define the array in the Code (["table1", "table2"]):
[image: Code]

The input in the UI will look like this:

[image: Right]

Now it works!
It seems, that the Datafactory is otherwise treating the whole array as one element of some array. Hence, the solution with the array() function sometimes works.
It looks like a bug, defining array parameter input..

(Had to edit the answer, I first thought omiting the colons in the UI input would be enough)

Answer (score -1):

Please try updating your dynamic expression of ForEach Items as below:

```
{
    "value": "@array(pipeline().parameters.TableNames)",
    "type": "Expression"
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks , this worked. I am wondering why my other pipes (having multiple tables or having array ) using pipeline().parameters.TableNames worked without specifying array until today? –

Comment: Pl look at the escape character issue which I am facing now. the select * from table is not working

Comment: The solution @array didnt work. It actually creates an array of all that is contained in item() and then select statement has all the tables in one statement. The objective is to have 1 table name in each loop.

Comment: The @array function shouldn't create any issue. For each iteration of ForEach activity you will have a single select statement. Also please enable "Sequential" properity of Foreach activity.  I have my pipeline with same setting and no issue. Could you please post your issue in ADF MSDN forum, that way I can provide you more screenshots and sample pipeline code for testing: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=AzureDataFactory - Thanks.

Comment: I enabled the Sequential so that helped,thanks. But escape char are not recognizable by the SQL   error:   "Code": 11000,
            "Message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid object name '\"fom.FOMLineItem_manual\"'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=1,Message=Invalid object name '\"fom.FOMLineItem_manual\"'.,},],

Comment: You can cleaerly see that the escape char is the issue, and i typed in the table names so there is no possiblility of typo. Input
{
    "source": {
        "type": "SqlServerSource",
        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT * FROM [\"fom.FOMLineItem_manual\"]"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "AzureBlobFSSink"

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/023ffa8f-82fc-41b3-9ed7-2acee7253e7e/azure-datafactory-v2-execute-pipeline-issue-with-escape-character-issue?forum=AzureDataFactory